# WordPress: Displaying placeholder text by post format

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post-format

I want to generate a placeholder-text in the 'content editor' if post has post format 'gallery'. But I can't get it working:

functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'wpse57907_default_content', 10, 2 );
function wpse57907_default_content( $content, $post ) {
    if ( 'post' == $post->post_type && has_post_format('gallery')) {
        $content = '<i style="color:#999">Use this area to upload and edit images... any text put in here will NOT be generated on the project&apos;s page. Please use the fields above for text.</i>';

    return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'wpse57907_default_content', 10, 2 );
function wpse57907_default_content( $content, $post ) {
    $format = get_post_format($post->ID);
    if ( 'post' == $post->post_type && $format == 'gallery') {
        $content = '<i style="color:#999">Use this area to upload and edit images... any text put in here will NOT be generated on the project&apos;s page. Please use the fields above for text.</i>';
    }
    return $content;    
}
```

Also, please make sure that your theme is set to actually have post-format support with add_theme_support and that your post has the correct post format (gallery).

Comment: I don't seem to get it working. Now if I change the post format to gallery no message appears.

Comment: Have you tried doing an echo $format before the if statement to see if the format is actually being pulled correctly?